# Writing the response from servlet to iframe

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets, web-applications

Content.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <iframe src="Response.jsp">
    </iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Response.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%="Loading..." %>
    <%
    try{
    Thread.sleep(6000);
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
    %>
    <%="Loaded" %>
    </body>
    </html>
```

In the above code I expect like in i frame the "Loaded" should be printed after 6 seconds of "Loading"
But here they both "Loading..." and "Loaded" get printed at the same time after 6 seconds.
I tried with flush () and flush Buffer ()
But if I Changed the "Loading..." as `"<H1> Loading... </H1>"` Its works fine as I expected. But I need to know is there some other way to do it???
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why i got down for this question but this is important question for my project..Please ask me if i am not clear. thanks

Comment: Is your scenario is like this ? Load the content.jsp page first, wait 6 seconds and then load response.jsp. right ?

Answer (score 0):

The server is sending the response as a single html page. So even though you put a sleep between the two statements both will displayed at client side at the same time. There are several approaches to do this.

Have a look at [Commet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

Comment: @ subir kumar Thanks..But if I changed the "Loading..." as "<H1> Loading... </H1>" its working fine. How can its possible ??